# How to search for new questions with an accepted answer

Tags: support, search

I would like to see new answers but only where an answer has been accepted.
Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking for, but...

Here's one to get accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=isaccepted%3a1

And here's one for questions with accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a1

Comment: Thanks thats helpfull! I see that there is Advanced Search Tips :D